# Do I need to pass data from the controller to the view in populating a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor-2

I'm currently studying asp.net mvc and I just started, I decided to move away from web forms to mvc.

I'm just curious because I have this code and I want to know the difference between passing the model in the `return View(data)` and not passing it.

Here's the code:

**The Controller**

```
/* Even if I comment/remove the lines ViewBag.GenreId....... and ViewBag.ArtistId
   and just return View(); everything seems to work fine. I'm following this music store tutorial from codeplex
*/

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Album album)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          db.Albums.Add(album);
          db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");  
     }
     //this will assign the values of the dropdownlist of the View
     //it will assign the values on the dropdownlist that has a name GenreId
     ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", album.GenreId);
     ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
     return View(album);
}
```

**The Code for the View**

```
@model CodeplexMvcMusicStore.Models.Album

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Album</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenreId, "Genre")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("GenreId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenreId)
        </div>
```

I would also like to know the difference between passing in the object model in `View(album)` vs not passing it `View()`.

Comment: If you do not pass object model in `return View(album)` it will not show any validation errors in your view if there are any. As you are using ViewBag for GenreId and ArtistId you can render in view without passing the object model to view (`return View()`).

Comment: The reason everything seems to work fine even if you remove/comment the ViewBag.GenreId and ViewBag.ArtistId may be because the ModelState is valid. You are checking the ModelState and redirecting back to Index Action if it is valid. I am pretty sure, if you comment/remove those lines and just return View(), you will get an error if the ModelState is invalid. This is because, your view is expecting Model of type CodeplexMvcMusicStore.Models.Album. You can test that by putting a break point on the 'if' condition and bypassing it to execute next statement outside 'if' to see if it really works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not pass object model in return View(album) it will not show any validation errors in your view if there are any. As you are using ViewBag for GenreId and ArtistId you can render in view without passing the object model to view (return View()) posted by Karthik

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, if you do not pass the model through then your page will not be populated.

Also it will not know where to bind the values back to when you post the form back.

Comment: Even if I comment/remove the lines ViewBag.GenreId....... and ViewBag.ArtistId
  and just return View(); everything seems to work fine. I'm following this music store tutorial from codeplex

Comment: It will load the page fine, but i would have thought the dropdown would be empty as it has not got any data being passed to it!

Answer (score 1):

If you dont pass the data then you cannot access the data in the razor. You need to pass your model to the `return View(model)` in order to use it on the Razor View. If you need to pass more than one model then you can pass you use either `ViewBag` or `ViewData` to do this.

By looking at your question. It seems to me you might be able to find your answer in this [MVC DropDownListFor tutorial](http://mvctutorialsandguides.blogspot.co.nz/2013/01/mvc-c-how-to-implement-dropdown-list.html)